# Convert datetime in Python string variable to proper format

Tags: python, json, datetime

I am a newbie to Python programming. 
I am trying to convert a YAML file to JSON file using python.
I am using pyyaml package for the conversion.
In the YAML file, there are some date values which are being converted to Datetime objects in Python. I need them to be converted as is or to a string.

**Sample YAML file:** http://pastebin.com/sdcx6sEJ

**Output String:** http://pastebin.com/Bvm5cNwH

**Output:**
{"meta": {"data_version": 0.6, "created": datetime.date(2013, 2, 22), "revision":1}

**Expected:**
{"meta": {"data_version": 0.6, "created": "2013-02-22", "revision":1}

```
sourcedir = "D:/YAML/"
targetdir = "D:/JSON/"
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(sourcedir):
    for file in files:
        # print os.path.join(subdir, file)
        filepath = subdir + file
        if filepath.endswith(".yaml"):
            with open(filepath, 'r') as src:
                try:
                    JSONfile = targetdir + file.replace("yaml", "json")
                    currentfile = open(JSONfile, 'w')
                    ymldata = yaml.load(src)
                    # print(ymldata)
                    ymldata = str(ymldata)
                    ymldata = ymldata.replace("'", "\"")
                    # ymldata = ymldata.replace("datetime.date(2005, 6, 13)", "\"2005-06-13\"")
                    print(ymldata)
                    json.loads(ymldata)
                    # jsondata = json.dumps(ymldata)
                    # jsonSTR = str(jsondata)
                    # currentfile.write(jsonSTR)
                except ValueError as exc:
                    print(exc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think calling pyyaml.safe_load() will prevent the creation of complex objects.  So that might work for you.

Comment: I am not having a datetime object as is, it is in embedded in the string. Update the question to include code. TIA.

Comment: Thanks, Lincoln for your time. I checked wih safe_load() and still getting the same datetime object in string.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is removing the !!timestamp tags from the yaml file

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: datetime.date(2013, 2, 22).isoformat()
Out[1]: '2013-02-22'
```

Or use manual formatting to get it anyway you want:

```
In [1]: datetime.date(2013, 2, 22).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[1]: '2013-02-22'

In [2]: datetime.date(2013, 2, 22).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
Out[2]: '2013/02/22'
```

etc

Comment: I am getting the text "datetime..." in the string and not the object itself. Updated the question to include code.

Comment: In your example output it's not datetime within the string but the actual object...?

Comment: Updated the question to include sample data.

Comment: I'm looking both at your file and your example and there's a datetime object in both of them `{"meta": {"data_version": 0.6, "created": datetime.date(2013, 2, 22), "revision":1}`

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your inner most try/except block (before json.loads()):

```
ymldata['meta']['created'] = ymldata['meta']['created'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```